# How to use a CSS Flexbox with divs that have different heights

Tags: html, css, ruby, flexbox, haml

I have a page with five different panels, and each panel has a different height associated with it, and some of them have different widths.  I've been wanting to use CSS Flexbox with the idea that these panels would stack on top of each other when they need to be responsive.

The problem I'm having is that when I've tried to use CSS Flexbox, it sets all of the divs to the exact same height,  which isn't really what I want here.

Here's my Haml which generates my HTML:

```
.property-information
  .general-information-panel
     enough content for a height of 60px;
  .government-information-panel 
     enough content for a height of 100px;
  .owner-information-panel 
     enough content for a height of 80px;
```

CSS:

```
.property-information{
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: .75;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.general-information-panel{
  background-color: #e7f5fe;
  width: 400px;
}
.government-information-panel{
  background-color: #e7f5fe;
  width: 500px;
}
.property-owner-information-panel{
  background-color: #e7f5fe;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Is it possible to use a CSS Flexbox, with divs or panels that have different heights?

Answer (score 0):

I started a snippet nevertheless I am not sure at all of your expectation.
A schema would be much appreciated.

After that, I could try to help you by editing this snippet.

```css
container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
}

row {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

#a {
  background-color: #fad390;
}

#b {
  background-color: #f8c291;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#c {
  background-color: #6a89cc;
}

#d {
  background-color: #82ccdd;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#e {
  background-color: #b8e994;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <row id="a"></row>
  <row id="b"></row>
  <row id="c"></row>
  <row id="d"></row>
  <row id="e"></row>
</container>
```

Comment: Rather than try to answer, and potentially find out it's off-track, instead ask for clarification and help the OP define the question better. Then answer. Not doing that results in questions and answers that wander.